# Sorting Options into groups from array (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a table of pages on a site and two of the fields are `template` and `url_title`. A template can belong to many urls but a url is unique and can have only one template. I wish to insert a dropdown list where each url is sorted underneath  its respected template. I have managed to add each option group once but for some reason when i try and the different options my query is only adding one. Also not sure if my method for doing this is kind of wrong. This is what i have...

```
    $findpagesString = "SELECT * FROM `cms` WHERE clickable ='Y' AND `status` = 'Y' ORDER BY `template` ASC";
    $findPagesQuery=$obj->multipleSelect($findpagesString);
    $templates = array();        

    while ($pagesVal = mysql_fetch_array($findPagesQuery=$obj->result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                        if (! in_array($pagesVal['template'], $templates)){
                            $template = $pagesVal['template'];
                            echo "<optgroup label='";
                            echo str_replace('.php', '', $pagesVal['template'])."'>";
                            while ($urlVal = mysql_fetch_array($findPagesQuery=$obj->result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

                                if ($urlVal['template'] == $template){
                                    echo '<option>';
                                    echo $urlVal['url_title'];
                                    echo '</option>';
                                }

                            }
                            echo "'></optgroup>";
                            array_push($templates, $pagesVal['template']);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Aside from having several unforgivable sins in the code, and lacking a proper explanation (like data structure and sample data), your only definite mistake is this at the end `echo "'></optgroup>";` What quote are you closing? And what tag? The HTML is simply invalid, whatever data you have. And you could identify that easily when you look at the actual HTML and see that all options are there.

Comment: I'm closing the <optiongroup> label. This is the part of the code that works. I'm kind of learning php at the moment so I kind of guessed i might not be using the best method. Please could you go into more detail about what the unforgivable sins are? Thanks.

Comment: No. The label gets closed here `echo str_replace('.php', '', $pagesVal['template'])."'>";` and even if it weren't, why would you contain `<option>` tags in a label?

Comment: That's a very good point! Thank you! :D

Comment: The sins are: 1. Using `mysql_*` functions which are deprecated and discouraged from use. 2. Spaghetti code - having everything - SQL, PHP, and HTML, in just a few lines of code. You need to separate the template (html) and the logic. That's one of the main reason why you got into this problem. That's the main reason people use frameworks, like Symfony or Laravel.

Comment: Please could you explain what my unforgivable sins are? I just want to get better. Thanks.

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated `mysql_` database library. It was discontinued several years ago due to security issues and removed entirely in PHP7. To protect yourself against likely security vulnerabilities in the library, and also to allow you to use measures such as prepared statements and parameterised queries to defend your data against SQL Injection attacks, I recommend you switch to using the `mysqli_` or `PDO` libraries as soon as possible. Also, if you ever upgrade to PHP7 your code will stop working entirely.

Comment: Great. Sorry for asking again. I edited the post so wasn't sure if you would see. It's actually someone else's site and I'm not being paid to completely skin everything. The site is kind of a mess. So I should use more functions?

Comment: mysql functions are being used all over the site so I figured I would just keep it consistent with that.

Comment: ok well if it's not your site you probably should keep it consistent. But you could perhaps point out to the regular maintainer that their code is very out of date and has security risks. I doubt you'll be thanked but it's the right thing to do!